# Nested Loops calculation output is incorrect, but program runs

Tags: python, nested-loops

How am I able to get my program to display year 1 for the first 12 months and then year 2 for the next 12 months if the input value for years = 2?

Also I don't know where my calculation is going wrong. According to my desired output, the total rainfall output should be 37, but I am getting 39.

[image: Added picture of current output. Total should be at 37 not 39. I also need the second batch of 12 months to say year 2]

```
#the following are the values for input:
#year 1 month 1 THROUGH year 1 month 11 = 1
#year 1 month 12 THROUGH year 2 month 12 = 2

def main():
    #desired year = 2
    years = int(input("Enter the number of years you want the rainfall calculator to determine: "))
    calcRainFall(years)

def calcRainFall(yearsF):
    months = 12
    grandTotal = 0.0

    for years_rain in range(yearsF):
        total= 0.0
        for month in range(months):
            print('Enter the number of inches of rainfall for year 1 month', month + 1, end='')
            rain = int(input(': '))
            total += rain
        grandTotal += total
    #This is not giving me the total I need. output should be 37.
    #rainTotal = rain + grandTotal
    #print("The total amount of inches of rainfall for 2 year(s), is", rainTotal)
    print("The total amount of inches of rainfall for 2 year(s), is", grandTotal)
main()
```

Comment: You're not using `years_rain` for anything. Try printing it instead of `year 1`.

Comment: that would not let me due to a syntax error.

Comment: What's the syntax error, and what's the code? Put it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've shortened your code a little bit. Hopefully this is a complete and correct program:

```
def main():
    years = int(input("Enter the number of years you want the rainfall calculator to determine: "))
    calcRainFall(years)

def calcRainFall(yearsF):
    months = 12 * yearsF # total number of months
    grandTotal = 0.0     # inches of rain

    for month in range(months):
        # int(month / 12): rounds down to the nearest integer. Add 1 to start from year 1, not year 0.
        # month % 12: finds the remainder when divided by 12. Add 1 to start from month 1, not month 0.
        print('Enter the number of inches of rainfall for year', int(month / 12) + 1, 'month', month % 12 + 1, end='')
        rain = int(input(': '))
        grandTotal += rain
    print("The total amount of inches of rainfall for", yearsF, "year(s), is", grandTotal)

main()
```

Comment: This did work, could you further explain how it is that it did that I am a bit lost on how it was able to go to year 2.

Comment: For the first 12 months (months = 0..11), months / 12 = 0 point something.
For the next 12 months (months = 12..23), months / 12 = 1 point something.
Using int() ignores the stuff after the decimal point. It basically gives the number of years starting from 0. Hence we + 1.

Answer (score 3):

Before the print statement, you don't need to add rain value again for rainTotal. This is because grandTotal accounts for the rain per year. And it is being added twice for two years already. So what you're doing is essentially adding the last value of rain twice (2 in this case)
Make your print statement this and remove rainTotal -

```
print("The total amount of inches of rainfall for 2 year(s), is", grandTotal)
```

Comment: That did the trick. Would you be able to help me make the second year output say year 2 and not year 1 again?

Comment: Use this inside your print statement
`print('Enter the number of inches of rainfall for year '+str(years_rain)+' month ', str(month + 1))
`

Comment: This made years start at 0

Comment: Make it str(years_rain + 1). Overlooked that, sorry!

Comment: It says that there's an invalid syntax. around the ' month ' part of the code

Comment: Check your brackets. It works completely fine for me.
`print('Enter the number of inches of rainfall for year '+str(years_rain)+' month '+ str(month + 1))`
Use a '+' to concatenate and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
rainTotal = rain + grandTotal
```

> is performing following: 2 + 37 because you have last rain input = 2 and already total or grandTotal is = 37 (total input for each year) so *rainTotal = rain + grandTotal* is **not needed**

Comment: I was able to change that in the most recent edit. Could you determine how to make the following 12 months year 2 instead of all the outputs being year 1?

Comment: so you need : year 1 = 12 months and calculate total and year 2 = 12 month and calculate total ?

Comment: My output will dish out 2 years because that's the value I input. How can I make it so 12 of those months are labeled as 'year 1' and the other 12 are labeled 'year 2'?

"Enter the number of inches of rainfall for year {this is the area where I need to have a 2 for the second half of the months} month 1"

Answer (score 0):

Notes for your code:

As stated earlier, rainTotal is unneeded.

You can try:

```
print 'Enter the number of inches of rainfall for year %d month %d' % (years_rain, month), end='')
```

This will fill the first %d for the value for years_rain and the second %d with the value for month as your for loops run.

This trick can also be used on the final print line as shown below:

```
print("The total amount of inches of rainfall for %d year(s) % yearsF, is", grandTotal)
```